# Is it possible set default animation theme for transaction in Android Navigation component?

Tags: android, animation, navigation, themes

I want change default transaction animation for Android Navigation Component like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="enterAnim">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="exitAnim">@anim/slide_out_left</item>
    <item name="popEnterAnim">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="popExitAnim">@anim/slide_out_left</item>
</style>
```

In this case, it didn't work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do this. Check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52413868/10213096

Comment: Yeap, but for material component theme it don't work.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65755470/2369484

Answer (score -1):

Release notes of Navigation `2.4.0-alpha02` says:

> When inflating an  element via XML, animation attributes can
> use attributes pulled from your theme using the
> app:enterAnim="?attr/transitionEnter" syntax

So, yes it is now possible to set a default animation for your navigation's actions.